# How to use inner touch coordinate with Draggable

Tags: flutter

[Here is an example of using `Draggable`.](https://github.com/rxlabz/flutter_dropcity/blob/master/img/dropcity_mobile.png)

Is there a possibility to get also like the **touch coordinate** within the Draggable widget? I illustrated what I'm searching for in the image with x1 and x2.

[image: Image - Touch x1 and x2]

So I want to determine one of the inner coordinates like x1 or x2.

Here is how I use draggable so far.

```
draggable = new Draggable(
    data: widget.text,
    feedback: avatar,
    child: item,
    onDraggableCanceled: (velocity, offset) {
      // the inner touch point is not included in offset ...
    },
);
```

[`Draggable` docs](http://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html)

If it doesn't work with Draggable. Is there an **alternative** which I can use?

Comment: Why do you need to determine the point of interaction?

Comment: I do need it because I want to place an image directly to the position where my finger dragged the widget to. So i just need the real position where the touch ended after dragging the widget.

Comment: Do you mean replace the widget that is being dragged with another widget after the drag is completed ?

Comment: First i drag to a another position and after releasing my touch a image or widget draws at the position where I released my finger. It is illustrated in this image https://imgur.com/NIYrWlj . After releasing it should look like this https://imgur.com/qvZTdzC

Comment: You can use the OnDraggablecancelled method for that you will get your solution. [Here you will find the implementation of the method](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Draggable/onDraggableCanceled.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your draggable widget in a Listener and you can do the below code.

```
onPointerDown: (PointerEvent event) {
            print("Touch Position Of your Widget ${event.position}");
          },
```